# Sharing data from a desktop application to a Windows 8 Metro application

Tags: windows, windows-runtime

I am wondering if anyone has come up with a technique for sharing data from a desktop application. Back in the Developer Preview Microsoft had the ability to share a screenshot from the desktop. In the Consumer Preview this feature disappeared and in the Release Preview isn't there either. I presume that the plumbing to do this is somewhere in there but haven't been able to get anything to work.

Comment: I'm looking for this as well.  Specifically, I want to invoke the share charm and support the share contract, not just move data from one specific app to another.  It boggles me that Windows Explorer is ignorant of share.  There ought to be a right click menu option to share a file at least!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make the desktop app an HTTP server and connect from the Metro one or simply write/read file(s) in a known folder under Documents.